# Magic Keyboard fn key does not have desired behavior with arrow keys

Tags: keyboard

I have a 2020 MBP running Catalina.  I just bought a Magic Keyboard for ergonomics, but the <kbd>fn</kbd> key (note: **not** the F1-F12 keys) doesn't modify the function of the arrow keys in the same way it does for my MBP's keyboard.

For example:
While using vim in terminal, my <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd> = <kbd>PgUp</kbd> on my MBP.  On my Magic Keyboard it is a single line up (same as when I don't press <kbd>fn</kbd> at all).

Another example:
While using PyCharm, <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> = <kbd>forward delete</kbd> with my MBP keyboard.  But on my Magic Keyboard it is a <kbd>backspace</kbd>.

I'd like my Magic Keyboard "bindings" to be similar to the MBP's keyboard.  Is this possible?

Comment: Not to address keyboard problem, but usage of Vim: why not ⌃+B (back full screen) or ⌃+F (forward full screen)?

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I get the feeling that this problem is more general than just the one Vim example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a very straightforward problem: the keyboard I bought was broken.  I got a replacement from my local Apple store and everything works as expected now.